# How to Convert a Webex ARF File on OSX (a Mac)

Tags: mac, video, mp4

My company is in the habit of adopting Windows-centric solutions.  The latest is Webex for hosting and recording meetings.  Webex records the meeting and makes the file available for download in the form of their proprietary ARF format. Predictably, their own player supports converting to MP4 only in the Windows version of the player, and not in the Mac version of the player.  So the question I have for this community is:

How do I convert an ARF file to an MP4 using a Mac?

Update:  Things I have tried:

1. Applications:

-- IdealShare VideoGo claims to convert ARF files on a Mac but this is not true. I downloaded their free trial and was told that ARF is not a valid media type.

-- Aiseesoft will come up in google searches as an option but their software is also PC only for purposes of converting ARF.

2. nbr2mp4 does not work on a Mac. You will get an error about not being able to open a display.

Comment: Are you familiar with the command line? If so, see [this post](http://blog.ricardoamaro.com/content/how-watch-arf-webex-files-your-linux-desktop).

Comment: Instead of using wget, use `curl -O -L http://support.webex.com/supportutilities/nbr2mp4.tar`

Comment: I downloaded and unpacked that utility from webex, but when I try running it on an arf file I get the following: [Roberts-MacBook-Pro:nbr2_mp4 Robert$ ./nbr2mp4 './Demos/Sprint\ 33\ Review.arf' ./Demos/ 5
nbr2mp4: unable to open display ""

Comment: Try ~/Demos/Sprint\ 33\ Review.arf instead of the .

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I still get: Mac:nbr2_mp4 Robert$ ./nbr2mp4 ~/Demos/Sprint_33.arf 5
nbr2mp4: unable to open display ""

Comment: @bret7600 The tar file is for Linux, it won't work on macOS. `nbr2mp4` is a shell script which tries to access `$DISPLAY` for X11.

Comment: @patrix thank you very much for the clarification.  I'll edit the post to make it more clear that I am looking for a solution for OS X.  Thanks!

Comment: It's not so much that it's "windows centric" is just that Cisco is a royal PITA.

Answer (score 2):

Webex has a Mac version of their player on their [player website](https://www.webex.com/play-webex-recording.html) available for download:

https://welcome.webex.com/client/T31L/mac/intel/webexnbrplayer_intel.dmg

The software will install, but (IMO) it doesn't create an application link in Finder or in Launch Pad.  I personally don't have any WebEx recordings I can use to test, but you can launch the player manually.  It's located in the *user's* library folder under:

```
~/Library/Application Support/WebEx Folder/500
```

I was able to launch the player by using Terminal and typing:

```
$ open ~/Library/Application Support/WebEx Folder/500/Network\ Recording\ Player.app
```

You could also open that folder in Finder and create an alias to put on your Desktop/Applications folder.

[image]

**Convert the Audio**

The kicker here is your are going to need another app to "grab" the audio.  You can use [Audio Hijack](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/buy.php) or [Soundflower](https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower).  You can also [do it via hardware](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/258912/119271) (less than $30) which will also give you a high quality USB audio interface that you can use for other purposes (I personally use this method for my iMac interface to my Bose Wave Radio).

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I am familiar with this player and indeed have it installed.  It is required to play ARF files on your Mac at all.  Unfortunately, this Mac Webex player does not offer the feature of converting files to MP4 (like its PC counterpart does).  As such, their own player is not a solution to this problem. Thanks again!!

Comment: Sorry...my attention got called away before I could finish....I added in a section about converting.

Comment: Looks like you need to use a third party app for this after all, and there are not any straight up conversion apps either, so you have to use a screencast type app.  I am leaning towards Ink2Go.